# Angular 9, Drag And Drop Nested Trees, not allowing to drag within originated droplist when linked to parent droplist

Tags: angular, tree, drag-and-drop, angular9

**Question**

Anyone who can help me figure out why dragging within the drop-list container does not work once you link the root drop-list with it's child drop-lists?

**Problem**

Dragging 'Item22' does not allow me to place it before 'Item21' but will always go to 'Root' drop-list, however it does allow me to place it before/after any item within 'List1'.

**Code**

The item list

```
items = [{id: '1', title: 'List1',
         children: [{id: '11', title: 'Item11'},
                    {id: '12', title: 'Item12'}
         ]},
         {id: '2',title: 'List2',
          children: [{id: '21', title: 'Item21'},
                     {id: '22', title: 'Item22'}
          ]}
        ];
```

used within this html page structure

```
<div
  cdkDropList
  id="0_root"
  [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="['1_1', '1_2','0_root']"
>
  <div *ngFor="let item of items" cdkDrag>
    <div *cdkDragPlaceholder class="fu"></div>
    <div>{{ item.title }}</div>
    <div
      cdkDropList
      [id]="'1_' + item.id"
      [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="['1_1', '1_2','0_root']"
    >
      <div *ngFor="let itemChild of item.children" cdkDrag>
        <div *cdkDragPlaceholder class="fu"></div>
        <div>{{ itemChild.title }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See example in following link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-p9fxfa

**Stuff i tried**

- I have tried looking at the enter and exit events of both cdkDrag and cdkDropList but both just don't trigger for the items original droplist.
- I cannot work with CdkDropListGroup as the treeview is build with recursive components.
- Tried to play with the order of connectTo but no resolution.
- It also does not matter if i include the droplist id in it's own connectedTo list.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hey Peter! Nice of you to have created a stackblitz. Maybe you should add some of your code directly as well in here to help people see your problem "at a glance". Happy coding! Cheers!

Comment: @Ardzii Thx for the comment added some code from the stackblitz directly in the question as well as some titles.